# componentDidUpdate() doesn't seem to get called after actual re-rendering occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

The basic code flow is like this.

#### item.js

```
export default class Item extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            modalIsOpen: false,
            logs: []
        };

        this._fetchLogs = this._fetchLogs.bind(this);
        this._fetchAnotherLogs = this._fetchAnotherLogs.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        let tableBody;

        if (this.state.logs.length > 0) {
            let body = [];
            this.state.logs.forEach((log) => {
                body.push(
                    <tr key={`log${log.id}`}>
                    <td>{log.operator_name} / {log.operator_code}</td>
                    </tr>
                );
            });

            tableBody = (
                <table className="logs">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                <th className="operator">{i18next.t('operator')}</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>{body}</tbody>
                </table>
            );
        }

        return (
            <div>
            <ul className="tabs">
            <li onClick={this._fetchLogs}>Logs</li>
            <li onClick={this._fetchAnotherLogs}>Another Logs</li>
            </ul>

            <div className="modalContent">
            {tableBody}
            </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log('didUpdate', $('.ReactModal__Content').height(), $(window).height());
    }

    _fetchLogs() {
        $.ajax({
            context: this,
            url: URL.DEVICE_LOGS(this.props.id),
            success(resp) {
                const logs = resp.data;
                this.setState({logs});
            },
            error(resp) {
                console.log(resp);
            },
        });
    }

    _fetchAnotherLogs() {
        $.ajax({
            context: this,
            url: URL.DEVICE_LOGS_ANOTHER(this.props.id),
            success(resp) {
                const logs = resp.data;
                this.setState({logs});
            },
            error(resp) {
                console.log(resp);
            },
        });
    }
};
```

So when the `<li>` element is clicked, it calls `_fetchLogs()`, which sets the `logs` state to some array from the server, and inside `render()`, it sets the `tableBody` variable and fills `<div className="modalContent">`.

What I want to achieve is that by using jQuery after the state changes and the component re-renders the table, measure the height of the table and changes some styles accordingly.

But what `componentDidUpdate()` logs out is the height before all the children(say, the `<table>`) are re-rendered.

For example, if I say the default height (without `<table`> content) is 170px, the after-height (with `<table>` content of logs) is 340px, and the after-height (with `<table>` content of another logs) is 500px, when I first click `<li>` it says the height is 170px although the result height is 340px actually. And if I click another `<li>` to fetch another logs, now it says the height is 340px, which is also wrong because it should be 500px.

So I'm thinking that `componentDidUpdate()` is called only after the state changes, not actual re-rendering (due to the state change) finishes. Is there something that I'm doing wrong or is there another options should I take into account?

### Edit 1

Following the Matthew Herbst's answer, which I thought is reasonable enough to be the right answer, I've made couple of changes but it didn't really change.

```
<div className="modalContent" ref={c => this._modalContent = c}>
    {tableBody}
</div>
```

And

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('didUpdate', this._modalContent.offsetHeight);
}
```

(I also tried to wrap it with jQuery but it didn't change...)

I tried to log out the sequence of rendering and `componentDidUpdate()` by adding `console.log()` right before the `render()`'s `return` (though it cannot be achieved this way, I know), it clearly shows that the array of objects log comes before the `didUpdate` log.

Comment: By observing Chrome's React Dev Tools, I can clearly see that the log comes first and the state change follows the log. Shouldn't it work this way?

Answer (score 1):

So, what's happening here is that you're not actually accessing the component in `componentDidMount`, you're accessing the DOM, which may not have been updated yet even though your component has rendered (remember, React has to render all the components that may have updated and then does a single DOM diff).

You are correct about using `componentDidUpdate`, but you are just accessing the wrong thing. What you needs are [`refs`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

In your `render`, add a `ref`:

```
return (
  <div>
    <ul className="tabs">
      <li onClick={this._fetchLogs}>Logs</li>
      <li onClick={this._fetchAnotherLogs}>Another Logs</li>
    </ul>
    <div 
      className="modalContent"
      ref={(myTableRef) => this.myTableRef = myTableRef}
    >
      {tableBody}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Then in your `componentDidUpdate`, you can do:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  console.log('didUpdate', $(this.myTableRef).height(), $(window).height());
}
```

That should give you the correct height for the table model.